# Comparing similarities between 2 data frames of different lengths in R

Tags: r

I have 2 simple but long dataframes and I would like to compare the column of 1 data frame to a specific column in another data frame to see how many and which values are the same.

For example, the word "HAT" might be present in row 1 in the 1st data frame, and it might be present in row 76 of the 2nd data frame. I want the output to tell me that the word "HAT" is present in both dataframes (along with all the other similarities), rather than just tell me how many values match up.

Please let me know if there is a function I can use! Comparedf is not working well. It would also be best if I could get the results in the form of another data frame.

Comment: What would be the contents of the resulting dataframe, apart from the values that appear in both?

Answer (score 0):

Using indexing and the `%in%` operator can help:

- use `%in%` to find which values in the first dataframe are also in the second dataframe
- use the logical vector to index the column, and return the corresponding values
- use `unique()` if you don't want repeats
- use `data.frame()` to construct a dataframe with one column of common values

```r
# create two example dataframes:
df1 <- data.frame(chars = rep(LETTERS[1:10], 2))
df2 <- data.frame(chars = LETTERS[8:20])
# find the common values:
df1$chars[df1$chars %in% df2$chars]
#> [1] "H" "I" "J" "H" "I" "J"
# alternatively, only show the unique values:
common <- unique(df1$chars[df1$chars %in% df2$chars])
# and create a dataframe from it:
common_df <- data.frame(common)
# see contents:
common_df
#>   common
#> 1      H
#> 2      I
#> 3      J
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: THANK U so much!! It worked! But do you know how to get the results in a data frame format rather than a character string? When I use data frame function it makes all the values (like H, I, J) into columns rather than making each one a row in one column.

Comment: I've added an extra step in my answer. Is that what you are after?